# Will Battlefield 3 shortcuts level you up?

Tags: battlefield-3

If you buy it when you start, will you go from Level 1 to a high(er) level?

I don't want to buy it, but I just wanna know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the vehicle/weapon shortcut bundles, No. They just give you the unlocks.